# Python can't find or install lxml

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pandas

In Win7, in python 3.4, in pandas, I tried to run pd.read_html.
It aborted, saying it couldn't find lxml.
I added "import lxml", and it said there was no module by that name.

I ran "pip install pandas lxml", and it aborted, saying

```
C:\Python34\hsf\pandas>pip install pandas lxml

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in c:\python34\
lib\site-packages

Downloading/unpacking lxml

  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Windows\l
xml\setup.py) egg_info for package lxml

    Building lxml version 3.4.4.
    Building without Cython.

    ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed *
*
```

I tried pip to install libxml2, and libxslt, and that aborted saying:

```
C:\Python34\lib\distutils\dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'bugtrack_url'

  warnings.warn(msg)

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Prior SO answers to similar questions said "use sudo..." so were inapplicable to windows.

How can I install lxml in python 3.4 on Win7 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
pip install lxml
```

For the vcvarvasall.bat you can try installing: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

If none of those work you can download the precompiled binary here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

The last option is the easiest.  Here are the steps:
1) Download the wheel at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml
2) `pip install wheel
3)`pip install "path to where you downloaded the *.whl from step 1"

Comment: Sigh! Downloaded and ran C:\Perl>pip install C:\Documents and Settings\Windows\Downloads\lxml-3.4.4-cp34-
none-win32.whl -- Got a screen full of unreadable red ink.

Comment: are you on 32 or 64 bit?  I assume it didn't work, try this wheel:lxml‑3.4.4‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl

Comment: Another screen with red ink. Last line says: ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'C:\\Documents', 'at', ':\\Documents'). I ahve no idea what that means. It looks like it's easier to scrape the file myself (which is what I'm doing now) than to download the file to make it 'easier'.

Comment: only other advice I can give is make sure not to run pip install in the same folder as where the .whl file is